# How do you use React context inside App.js file?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-context

I am building a multi-language app. I am using react-intl. So far, so good. I made a state of the language with context api, so I can switch it easily. However I get this error when I try to use the state in App.js: **TypeError: Object is not iterable (cannot read property Symbol(Symbol.iterator)).**

Here is my context file:

```
import React, {useState, createContext} from 'react'


export const LanguageContext = createContext();

export const LanguageProvider = (props) => {
const [language, setLanguage] = useState('')

return (
    <LanguageContext.Provider value = {[language,setLanguage]}>
        {props.children}
    </LanguageContext.Provider>
)
}
```

And here is the App.js:

```
function App() {
const [language, setLanguage] = useContext(LanguageContext)
return (
<LanguageProvider>
  //i tried using locale={language} 
  <I18nProvider locale={LOCALES.language}>
    <CartProvider>
      <TableProvider>
        <div className="App">
          <Router>
            <Header />
            <Switch>
              <Route path='/Cart' component={Cart} />
              <Route path='/:group/:subGroup/:item' component={Item} />
              <Route path='/:group/:subGroup' component={Items} />
              <Route path='/' exact component={Home} />
              <Route path='/:group' component={Groups} />
            </Switch>
          </Router>
        </div>
      </TableProvider>
    </CartProvider>
  </I18nProvider>
</LanguageProvider>
);
}
```

export default App

Here is the locale file that Im using to pass to the I18nProvider :

```
export const LOCALES = {
ENGLISH : 'en',
FRENCH: 'fr'
}
```

And where I change the context value(another component, not App.js):

```
const [language, setLanguage] = useContext(LanguageContext)
```

following line is cut from jsx:

```
onClick={() => setLanguage('en')}
```

I thinks the problem might be because I am trying to access the context before the App.js return statement, where the provider wraps the children but even if this is the case, I still don't know what might fix it. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I thinks the problem might be because I am trying to access the context before the App.js return statement

You're right this is the problem.

Depending on where you want to use `useContext` you could create an extra component that is a child of `LanguageProvider`. Then inside this child you are able to use `useContext`.

To give a simplified example:

```
const App = () => {
  const [language, setLanguage] = useContext(LanguageContext);
  useEffect(() => {
    setLanguage('en');
  }, []);
  return <p>{language}</p>;
};

export default function AppWrapper() {
  return (
    <LanguageProvider>
      <App />
    </LanguageProvider>
  );
}
```

Comment: Okay, but what gets rendered by the ReactDOM in the end in this case? App or Appwrapper?

Comment: `AppWrapper`. You can name these components to something else, I've just chosen a generic name to illustrate the idea.

Comment: You are a god, I don't know how I have not thought of this. It makes perfect sense. Thank you very much dude

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem trying to apply an authentication flow with react-navigation v5. I tried to follow the documentation as it is:
[Authentication flows with react-navigation v5](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/auth-flow/) But when trying to mix it with Context I run into the same issue

As in the previous Answer, I solve it in the same way.
Here it's an example where it has 3 possible Screens Stacks:

I create a component where I'll be using the context

```
const RootStack = () => {
  const { state } = useContext(AuthContext);
  return (
      <Stack.Navigator>
          {false ? (
              <Stack.Screen name="Splash" component={SplashScreen} />
          ) : state.token === null ? (
              <Stack.Screen
                name="Authentication"
                component={AuthenticationStack}
                options={{
                  title: 'Sign in',
                  headerShown: false,
                  animationTypeForReplace: false ? 'pop' : 'push',
                }}
              />
          ) : (
              <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={AppStack} />
          )}
      </Stack.Navigator>
      );
  };
```

And then I insert the component inside the provider:

```
export default ({ navigation }) => {
  return (
    <AuthProvider>
      <NavigationContainer>
        <Stack.Navigator>
          <Stack.Screen
            name="RootStack"
            component={RootStack}
            options={{
            headerShown: false,
            }}
          />
        </Stack.Navigator>
      </NavigationContainer>
    </AuthProvider>
  );
};
```